# Detectar y temporizar interacciones dentro de sitio web

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

¿Alguien me puede ayudar a conocer el tiempo que transcurre entre que una persona hace click en un botón (que abre una ventana con una web externa), hasta que la cierra o vuelve a mi web?

El objetivo de este código es obtener un tiempo con el que determinar si una persona ha estado el tiempo suficiente en un sitio web como para realizar una determinada acción.

He buscado en muchos lugares de todas las formas posibles y en varios idiomas, pero todo lo que encuentro son métodos que solo funcionan si la web abierta es tuya, y no es mi caso:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    //acción
}
```

Si no me pueden escribir el código, también me es útil una fuente donde averiguarlo o el nombre del "*método*" a usar para encontrar información sobre su uso.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estoy seguro de que esto solucione tu problema al 100%, pero se puede intentar. Se me ocurre que puedes "jugar" con los eventos *focus* y *blur* para poder controlar cuando el usuario vuelve o sale de tu pantalla.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(window).on('blur', function(){
        console.log('se ha perdido el foco');
      });

      $(window).on('focus', function(){
        console.log('tiene el foco');
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias zeros!! Esto me viene genial ;)

Comment: Me alegra que te sirviera. No hay de que :)